# Exclude given columns when sorting a table python

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort a table but would like to exclude given columns by their names while sorting. In other words, the given columns should remain where they were before sorting. This is aimed at dealing with columns like "Don't know', "NA" etc.

The API I'm using is unique and company specific but it uses python.

A table in this API is an object which is a list of rows, where each row is a list of cells and each cell is a list of cell values.

I am currently have a working function which sorts a table but I would like to edit/modify this to exclude a given column by it's name but I am struggling to find a way.

FYI - "Matrix" can be thought of as the table itself.

```
def SortColumns(byRow=0, usingCellValue=0, descending=True):
"""
:param byRow: Use the values in this row to determine the sort order of the 
        columns.
:param usingCellValue: When there are multiple values within a cell use this
        to control which value row within each cell is used for sorting
        (zero-based)
:param descending: Determines the order in which the values should be
        sorted. 
"""

   for A in range(0,Matrix.Count):
        for B in range(0,Matrix.Count):
            if(A==B):
                continue; #do not compare rows against eachother

            valA = Matrix[byRow][A][usingCellValue].NumericValue if Matrix[byRow][A].Count > usingCellValue else None;
            valB = Matrix[byRow][B][usingCellValue].NumericValue if Matrix[byRow][B].Count > usingCellValue else None;

            if(descending):
                if valB < valA:
                    Matrix.SwitchColumns(A,B)
            else:
                if valA < valB:
                    Matrix.SwitchColumns(A,B)
```

I am thinking of adding a new parameter which takes a list of column names, and use this to bypass these columns.

Something like:

```
def SortColumns(fixedcolumns, byRow=0,usingCellValue=0,descending=True):
```

Comment: Please clarify. What do you mean by "exclude"? The resulting sorted list should not have the excluded items? The list should be sorted, except the excluded items remain where they started?

Comment: The list should be sorted except for the excluded item, they should remain where they originally where. This is aimed at dealing with columns like "don't know", "NA" etc.

Comment: I guess I should have guessed that from your `fixedcolumns` parameter :-). Another question: is `Matrix` a list? Does it have a `.sort` method? I ask because lists usually don't have a `.Count` attribute.

Comment: Matrix is a list of lists but it does not have a .sort method unfortunately. The function about, we iterate over the columns and compare one column's data against another and switch them if one if greater than the other.

Comment: Just to confirm: `Matrix` is _like_ a list, but is not actually an instance of the built-in `list` type? Because if it was, it would definitely have a `sort` method.

Comment: That is correct. Apologies for the confusion but I'm finding to explain as I'm fairly new to the programming world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While iterating through the columns, You can use the `continue` statement to skip over columns that you don't want to move. Put these conditions at the start of your two loops:

```
for A in range(0,Matrix.Count):
    a_name = ??? #somehow get the name of column A
    if a_name in fixedcolumns: continue
    for B in range(0,Matrix.Count):
        b_name = ??? #somehow get the name of column B
        if b_name in fixedcolumns: continue
        if(A==B):
            continue
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I will test this shortly and report back!